# firefox mediaelement.js

Tags: firefox, drupal, mp3, mediaelement.js

I am trying to use the mediaelement.js library with Drupal. When I install the mediaelement drupal module and js library I am able to play MP3 files on all browsers except Firefox. It appears there is an issue with the Flash Fallback. But on the mediaelement.js page I see the MP3 player working in FF.

How can I diagnose this issue? What steps can I talk to find out if it is this version of the JS library, the Drupal module, or something I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, there are 2 things I suggest:

1. Add MIME-Type:
   Add new mime type for your media types into your server config or directly in `.htaccess`
   E.g. in my case I added

   ```
   AddType video/mp4 .mp4
   ```

   at the end of `.htaccess` to make it work in FF
2. Make sure that mediaplayer is initialized correctly and that all paths are set 
   up correctly. Check `pluginPath` and `flashName` properties.

Check http://mediaelementjs.com/#installation for more info.